# Saving to a file all parameters fed into a function in Python

Tags: python, json, parameter-passing, file-writing

I have a function in python that takes a number of arguments:

```
def do_something(epochs=1000, no_of_points=15, do_well=True, activation_function=torch.nn.ReLU()):

   all_params = locals()
   # code omitted
   return all_params
```

I call this function from some other file with the line:

```
do_something(5000, 10, False, torch.nn.Tanh())
```

I want to save all the parameters that are fed into this function (the values and the names of the parameters) and I want to save that to a readable (non-binary) file if possible so that I can copy and paste. So the file should contain something like:

```
{"epochs":5000, "no_of_points":15, "do_well":True, "activation_function":torch.nn.ReLU()}
```

How can I best do this? Dumping to JSON is problematic due to the fact that the object ReLU() is passed as an argument, it throws an error. Is there a common/standard practise for this?

Comment: - Well if you want to serialize a custom object you can use ``pickle``. [here](https://pythonexamples.org/python-pickle-class-object/) is a simple walk through.
 - If you insist on saving a ``json`` for readability purposes you have to involve some metadata. [Here](https://realpython.com/python-json/#encoding-and-decoding-custom-python-objects) is another walk through for that.